# Influx use data from query

Tags: influxdb

I want to calculate the daily average temperature by doing:
Take first value each hour -

```
query1 = SELECT first("value") FROM "externaltemp" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time(1h) fill(none)
```

And with those values I want to take the average value per day.
`SELECT mean(query1)` ... ?

My question is how to combine one query and use the data from the first to the next. Is that possible?

EDIT:

Added some data:

`Time   externaltemp.distinct
2018-04-04 07:07:00 3.80
2018-04-04 07:05:00 3.80
2018-04-04 07:04:00 3.80
2018-04-04 07:03:00 3.80
2018-04-04 07:02:00 3.80
2018-04-04 07:01:00 3.80
2018-04-04 07:00:00 3.80
2018-04-04 06:59:00 3.80
2018-04-04 06:58:00 3.80
2018-04-04 06:57:00 3.80
2018-04-04 06:56:00 3.80
2018-04-04 06:55:00 3.80
2018-04-04 06:54:00 3.80
2018-04-04 06:53:00 3.70
2018-04-04 06:52:00 3.80
2018-04-04 06:51:00 3.70
2018-04-04 06:50:00 3.70
2018-04-04 06:49:00 3.70
2018-04-04 06:48:00 3.70
2018-04-04 06:47:00 3.80
2018-04-04 06:46:00 3.70
2018-04-04 06:45:00 3.70
2018-04-04 06:44:00 3.70
2018-04-04 06:43:00 3.70`

And with query:
`SELECT first("value") FROM "externaltemp" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time(1h)`

`Time   externaltemp.first
2018-04-04 07:00:00 
3.80
2018-04-04 06:00:00 3.70
2018-04-04 05:00:00 2.90
2018-04-04 04:00:00 2.60
2018-04-04 03:00:00 2.20
2018-04-04 02:00:00 1.90
2018-04-04 01:00:00 2.30
2018-04-04 00:00:00 3.60
2018-04-03 23:00:00 5.50
2018-04-03 22:00:00 6.50
2018-04-03 21:00:00 7.50`

Comment: Share sample data...

Answer (score 0):

USE below code

```
SELECT MEAN("first") FROM (SELECT first("value") FROM "externaltemp" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time(1h) fill(none))
```

Comment: OK. I tested the query but then I only got
`
Time  externaltemp.mean
1970-01-01 01:00:00 -4.00
`
And before it looks like
`
Time  externaltemp.first
2018-03-03 22:00:00 -3.90
2018-03-03 21:00:00 -4.00
2018-03-03 20:00:00 -4.00
2018-03-03 19:00:00 -2.90
2018-03-03 18:00:00 -1.50
`